# Override Laravel Spark controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I am trying to play a bit around with Laravel Spark, and as a test I'd like to override the "Create API Token" request.

I notice the endpoint being used, when a user should create an API token is this:

```
POST     | settings/api/token | Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Settings\API\TokenController@store
```

So according to their [guide on customization](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/9.0/customization) you should use their `Spark::swap` method.

So I have tried adding below piece of code into `SparkServiceProivder@booted`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
use Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Settings\API\TokenController;

use Laravel\Spark\Http\Requests\Settings\API\CreateTokenRequest;

Spark::swap(
    TokenController::class . '@store',
    function(CreateTokenRequest $request) {
        exit('Hello World');
    }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a code like this in the SparkServiceProvider.php register function:

```
$this->app->singleton(
    'Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController',
    'App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController'
);
```

And then extend the App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController with Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController and change the items you need to.

Comment: Just an example basically you can do the same for Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Settings\API\TokenController

Comment: $this->app->singleton(
    \Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController:class,
    \App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController::class
);

works now too.